# Complex if statement in Excel

Tags: excel

Can someone explain the following excel formula to me:

```
=IF(OR(,AND(AE47<>"",AE48="",X$38=TRUE,Y$38=TRUE),AH48<>"",
AND(AE47=AE46,AE47<>"",AE48="",X$38=FALSE),
AND(AE48<>"",AE49="",X$38=TRUE,Y$38=FALSE)),$U$33,"")
```

I'm confused about the `=IF(OR(,AND` at the beginning of the statement. Does the "or" go with only the first "and" or does it apply to all of them? I'm trying to convert this to javascript.

Comment: Well, this is explicitly parenthesized prefix notation. Easier to parse than infix since it does not rely on implicit precedence rules.

Comment: Splitting it like this http://pastebin.com/ujaiPF5B helps identify whats going on, but it still looks weird and pointless.

Comment: Which is the cell this formula is written in? I'd need that reference  to get an accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting to understand better:

```
=IF(
     OR(
         AND(AE47<>"",AE48="",X$38=TRUE,Y$38=TRUE),
         AH48<>"",
         AND(AE47=AE46,AE47<>"",AE48="",X$38=FALSE),
         AND(AE48<>"",AE49="",X$38=TRUE,Y$38=FALSE)
       ),
       $U$33,  << "If True" result
       ""      << "If False" result
 )
```

The `OR` applies to all of the tests contained within its parentheses: if any of them evaluate to `True` then the formula returns the value of U33: otherwise an empty string.

The comma here `=IF(OR(,AND` seems like a typo.